# Autocomplete on "Unlimited" text field?

Tags: 6, entities, ajax

I'm adding Drupal's built in Autocomplete functionality using hook_form_alter to set the #autocomplete_path like so:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  ...
  $form['field_company']['und'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'autocomplete/company';
  ...
}
```

This works perfectly for a text field where the number of values is 1, but doesn't work when the number of values is unlimited. I'm assuming this has something to do with the field be added via Javascript. Is there another hook I can tap in to in order to add the #autocomplete_path?

EDIT : Drupal 6.

Comment: same issue here. Solved the problem with an alternate method using [autocomplete_widgets](http://drupal.org/project/autocomplete_widgets). But it will be helpful if anyone found solution to above problem!

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work" ?

Comment: @GregoryKapustin for unlimited value, field will no longer autocomplete ,if we click add more. it will revert back to textfield

Answer (score 4):

You have to iterate your field's delta ; here, you only affect `$form['field_company']['und']__[0]__, not  $form['field_company']['und']__[n]__`

Stay in your `hook_form_alter` but iterate it each time your `$form` is rebuild :

```
    foreach($form['field_company']['und'] as $delta => $field) {
        if(is_array($field) && is_numeric($delta)) {
            $form['field_company']['und'][$delta]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'autocomplete/company';
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's added with ajax, by field_add_more_js (if you have js enabled) and field_add_more_submit (either way) in field.form.inc . Anyway, use my code, it works, because your hook_form_alter is called on form_rebuild, which happens in that case.

Comment: Not working .after clicking add more it reverted back to textfield!

Comment: I test again and come back to you.

Comment: I'm sorry it works perfectly for me... :(

Comment: I am using drupal6 and my field is like this `$form['field_test'][0]['#autocomplete_path']`

Comment: D'oh, Drupal 6. Try without the ['value'] then ? I don't know, sorry.

Comment: yes tried without value only ..works first time. But clicking add more, reverted back :(

Comment: For debugging, disable JS in your browser and add a `dpm($form);` it will show you the $form renderable array to act on.

Comment: #autocomplete_path is correctly added when add another click. The problem is something related to js or attach behavior!!

Answer (score 1):

When altering a field with cardinality, I like to use [#process](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#process). Basically you are defining a function that will get called everytime the field is processed on the form including when added via javascript.

In your case, the code might look like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  ...
  $form['field_company'][$form['field_company']['#language']]['#process'][] = 'field_company_process';  
  ...
}

function field_company_process($element, &$form_state, $complete_form) {
  $element[$element['#max_delta']]['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'autocomplete/company';
  return $element;
}
```